# How to add curve widget to n-panel?

Tags: python, interface, geometry-nodes, source-code

So, I have one value controlled by the Float Curve node (in the geometry nodes). And I am trying to get an access to that float curve through the N-panel. It looks like Curve Widgets are available in Blender UI, but I just don't get how to create one and connect my Float Curve node with the curve widget. Any suggestions?

P.S. Right now I am drawing all the inputs from my Geometry Nodes groups to the n-panel. But all of them are floats and integers. But if there's any way to add a curve controller to the geometry node input it will be displayed on my panel as well. But I also can not find a solution on how to add the curve controller right to the group inputs (and I am not sure it is even possible).

Comment: This should help I think https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_curve_mapping or that https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.template_curveprofile